# Volume and surface of knock out drum

Tags: surfaces, volume

I have to calculate the volume and the surface of some KO drums (knock out drum).

To avoid ambiguous understandings here's a picture of one:
http://www.zamilsteel.com/ped/images/projects/11.jpg

I created a "skeleton" of this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDhWs.png

I know how to calculate the volume and surface of a cylinder based on the given parameters (d, h, w), so actually I only would like to know the formulas of the yellow part.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I'd say it's a spherical cap.

Comment: If the yellow part is a half of an ellipsoid, then the volume is simply
$\frac{2\pi}{3} h\left(\frac{d}{2}\right)^2 = \frac{\pi h d^2}{6}$.  
However, to my naked eye, the corresponding part on your first picture doesn't look like an ellipsoid. It looks more like a spherical cap with edges rounded at those place where it touches the cylinder. I don't think you have enough information to compute the actual volume.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I think the spherical cap's volume and surface will be it.

Comment: I found the surface computing of the spherical cap on wikipedia, but what if I don't know the r? How can I ignore or substitute it with something?

Comment: It's: pi * (a^2 + h^2), where a is d/2.